# LinearLayout child pushes other views

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

My activity's main layout is a `LinearLayout`. It has two children as an example. A `RelativeLayout` and a Button. The width and height of `RelativeLayout` are set to `match_parent` and the Button, `match_parent` and `wrap_content`. Unfortunately, `RelativeLayout` pushes the button below until it is not visible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Why is this happening? I tried a tweak for the `RelativeLayout` which is changing the height to `0dp` and weight to 1. It does make the Button visible but I am not sure if this is advisable as I only changed the height and weight of `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

OR

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/disha"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="NIlu"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

`LinearLayout` is either Vertical or Horizontal. Your first child which is `RelativeLayout` is `matchParent` then it will cover whole Outer layout .
Solution can be multiple its depends upon where exactly you want to place your `Button` . One way is .

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your Code Like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Worked Foe me..
you should Give `android:layout_weight="1"` to relative Layout

Comment: if you dont want to change your root layout then use my ans. also you can follow @nilu' s ans

Comment: Thanks buddy @LearningAlways

Answer (score 0):

//try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work just fine.

> I tried a tweak for the RelativeLayout which is changing the height to
>   0dp and weight to 1

the code look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your layout, `RelativeLayout` is the first child of your `LinearLayout`. Since, you have set the height and width to `match_parent` it takes up all available space pushing the button out of the view.

When you set the `RelativeLayout` height to `0dp` and weight to 1, `LinearLayout` first lays out all children based on the dimensions specified, and then distributes the remaining space based on the weight. In this case, the relative layout is `0dp`, so it takes no space in first pass, and the button takes up space based on its `onMeasure` (lets say `100dp`). The remaining space is now given to `RelativeLayout` because its weight is set to 1. Refer to the LinearLayout documentation for more details [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html).

You should consider using a `RelativeLayout`/`ConstraintLayout` as your root element.